# reload application.yml in spring-boot

Tags: java, spring-boot

I want to download sample_private.key some other location and given path location in Application-test.yml.
sample_private.key file is every time change . I need to reload Util configuration. Util.java is from some other repo. So we can’t modify.

```
@Configuration
public class Util {

  private final String privateKeyLocation;

  @Autowired
  public Util(
      @Value(“${parent.child.privateKeyLocation}") String privateKeyLocation
     ) {
    this.privateKeyLocation = privateKeyLocation;
  }


Application-test.yml
parent:
  child:
    privateKeyLocation: sample_private.key
```

Is any way to reload applicationContext/Application-test.yml.  I did some way but not working like below

```
1.@DirtiesContext
2.((ConfigurableApplicationContext) applicationContext).refresh();
```